# How to print string in this way

Tags: python, regex

For every string, I need to print # each 6 characters.

For example:

```
example_string = "this is an example string. ok ????"

myfunction(example_string)

"this i#s an e#xample# strin#g. ok #????"
```

What is the most efficient way to do that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this?

```
'#'.join( [example_string[a:a+6] for a in range(0,len(example_string),6)])
```

It runs pretty quickly, too.  On my machine, five microseconds per 100-character string:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.Timer( "'#'.join([s[a:a+6] for a in range(0,len(s),6)])", "s='x'*100").timeit()
4.9556539058685303
```

Comment: It may be better to use `xrange` instead of `range` in Python 2.x.

Comment: It's not likely to make much difference unless perhaps you're processing rather long strings.  On my machine, the difference with xrange() is a few tenths of a microsecond.  (This matches the note in the python 2.6 docs for xrange().)

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> str = "this is an example string. ok ????"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("(.{6})", r"\1#", str)
'this i#s an e#xample# strin#g. ok #????'
```

Update:
Normally dot matches all characters except new-lines. Use `re.S` to make dot match all characters including new-line chars.

```
>>> pattern = re.compile("(.{6})", re.S)
>>> str = "this is an example string with\nmore than one line\nin it. It has three lines"
>>> print pattern.sub(r"\1#", str)
```

> `this i#s an e#xample# strin#g with#`
>   `more #than o#ne lin#e`
>   `in i#t. It #has th#ree li#nes`

Comment: Flip the `re.DOTALL` flag aka `re.S` (single line mode) to make dot match them all. See the update @John

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools

def every6(sin, c='#'):
  r = itertools.izip_longest(*([iter(sin)] * 6 + [c * (len(sin) // 6)]))
  return ''.join(''.join(y for y in x if y is not None) for x in r)

print every6(example_string)
```